# django orm how to make sure postgres array field is not an empty list?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have the following model for `django`. This model creates an array field called `metric_vals` but it is allowing the array to be an empty array. Is there a way of making sure the array is always a non empty array?

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    metric_vals = ArrayField(models.FloatField(null=False), null=False, default=list)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    metric_vals = ArrayField(models.FloatField(null=False), null=False, default=list)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.metric_vals == []:
            raise ValidationError('Empty list not allowed')

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `validators` kwarg:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.validators import ArrayMaxLengthValidator, ArrayMinLengthValidator


def get_default_list():
    return [float(1), float(2)]

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    metric_vals = ArrayField(
        models.FloatField(null=False), 
        null=False, 
        # ensure the default passes the validation
        default=get_default_list,
        # like this
        validators=[
           ArrayMinLengthValidator(2),
           ArrayMaxLengthValidator(10),
        ]
    )
```

Related:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/validators/